# How to append a # to the filename from a MS Access attachment field if it exists

Tags: database, if-statement, ms-access, file-upload, data-entry

Hi I have 4 attachment fields in my form in my Access DB, and 2 textboxes. (txt_file1, txt_dest1)
One textbox for the source file and another for the destination file.
I am trying to figure out how to append a # to the filename if the file exists.
Currently it is just overwriting the existing file.

Ex.  
Office Safety Training_Cert_dnye_2022-03-18 
Office Safety Training_Cert_dnye_2022-03-18(2) 
Office Safety Training_Cert_dnye_2022-03-18(3)  
Office Safety Training_Cert_dnye_2022-03-18(4)

I am thinking maybe a loop incrementing an integer, and append that integer to the filename?
The filename is made up of a textbox field called "title" + access username + the date.

Here is how I am checking  to see if the file exists:

File exists module:

```
Public Function FileExists(ByVal path_ As String) As Boolean
  FileExists = (Len(Dir(path_)) > 0) 
End Function
```

I was thinking this
if the file exists, I want to append a # to the destination textbox text
otherwise just set the destination normally:

```
If FileExists(txt_dest1) Then
   'MsgBox ("File Exists")
Else
   Me.txt_dest1.Text = DestFolder1 & "\" & txt_Title.Value & "_" & "Cert" & "_" & TempVars![GlbUserName] & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".pdf"    'GetFilenameFromPath(vrtSelectedItem) & "\"
End If
```

Comment: Why are you using Text property? If you want to append a number then why aren't you? If file exists then why do you need to rename? Why would just constructing a string overwrite a file? Not clear what you want to accomplish nor what is actually happening.

Comment: I will add some text to my question. Instead of overwriting the file everytime, I want it to append a number to the filename. Ex. Office Safety Training_Cert_dnye_2022-03-18, Office Safety Training_Cert_dnye_2022-03-18(2), Office Safety Training_Cert_dnye_2022-03-18(3)

Comment: I still don't understand. If there is only one file, then why would you need to append a number? Sure, can have a loop for however many iterations you want. If you don't want to overwrite a file, then you want to copy it?

Comment: "I have 4 attachment fields"
Currently these all end up having the same file name, so I need to add a unique id to the naming convention.

Comment: So you are not overwriting a file, you are overwriting a field content. Okay, so use a `For x = 1 to 4` loop.

Comment: I just thought of the easiest solution for me, instead of appending a number after the filename, I should figure out how to get the filenames from the attachment fields and appending those to the textboxes with the new filenames.

Comment: An Attachment field is a multi-value field. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-lookup-and-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a#bm3. I don't use multi-value fields. And as for Attachment field, embedded files use up Access 2GB size limit.